# How can I generate my own Fernet key in Python?

Tags: python, cryptography, byte, valueerror, fernet

I've tried something like this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode as b64e
    bytes_gen = b64e(PASSWORD.encode())
    if len(bytes_gen) < 32:
        bytes_gen += b'=' * (32 - len(bytes_gen))
    elif len(bytes_gen) > 32:
        bytes_gen = bytes_gen[:32]
    print(bytes_gen, len(bytes_gen))
    f = Fernet(bytes_gen)
```

Terminal:

```
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading it wrong. The key is a cryptographic keys, which are usually 16, 24 or 32 bytes in size. So the phrase "Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes." doesn't mean that the encoding needs to be 32 *characters* in size, it means that there are 32 bytes that need to be encoded.

You seem to want to use a password instead of a key though. In that case you need to read the [appropriate section in the manual](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet) that explains how PBKDF2 can be used to *derive* a key from a password.